# How to determine if it is legal to remove credit link from theme?

Tags: theme-development

I have downloaded a theme and modified few things and customised it according to my needs. Now I want to remove the credits i.e. the back link to the designers site. I want to know if its legal for me to remove that. What are the terms and conditions?

Theme is http://diovo.com/links/voidy/
Credits is a backlink: Theme by Niyaz Diovo (with link)

Comment: How are we supposed to know what theme it is..

Comment: Which theme is it? Name please.

Comment: Please specify clearly what is theme name, from where u download, where the credits are mention in the theme. eg -footer, header, sidebar etc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theme licensing information is typically included in `style.css`. According to that Voidy theme is at least partially under [GPL license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License) (version not specified):

> The CSS, XHTML and design is released under GPL

There is no issue with removing front-end credits/link from GPL-licensed theme.